# Convert factor(non-uniform) to date in R?

Tags: r, date

I have dates in this format:

Apr-12,
Dec-12,
30-Jul-14,
Mar-16,
29-Feb-16,
May-17,
20-Nov-14,

R is treating it like factor variable. I want it to treat it like a date, and wherever the day of the date is missing, it should replace it with 1st.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to parse them separately because the format is not consistent. We first parse the ones which have date, month and year component. The ones which return `NA`'s are then parsed by adding "01" in them.

```
new_x <- as.Date(x, "%d-%b-%y")

new_x[is.na(new_x)] <- as.Date(paste0("01-", x[is.na(new_x)]), "%d-%b-%y")

new_x

#[1] "2012-04-01" "2012-12-01" "2014-07-30" "2016-03-01" "2016-02-29" "2017-05-01"
#[7] "2014-11-20"
```

Read more about formats at `?strptime`.

**data**

```
x <-factor(c("Apr-12", "Dec-12", "30-Jul-14", "Mar-16", "29-Feb-16",
            "May-17","20-Nov-14"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally append a "01-" when the first three characters are not in the system vector, `month.abb`

```
as.Date( ifelse( substr(dtvec,1,3) %in% month.abb, paste0("01-",dtvec), dtvec) ,"%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2012-04-01" "2012-12-01" "2014-07-30" "2016-03-01" "2016-02-29" "2017-05-01" "2014-11-20"
```